# STL map construction

Tags: c++

```
class Garage {
    string WorkerFirstName;
    string WorkerLastName;
    string WorkerNumber;
public:
    Garage()
    {
        WorkerFirstName = "";
        WorkerLastName = "";
        WorkerNumber = "";
    }

    void SetFirstName(string FirstName) { WorkerFirstName = FirstName;}    
    void SetLastName(string LastName) { WorkerLastName = LastName; }
    void SetNumber(string Number) { WorkerNumber = Number; }

    string GetFirstName() { return WorkerFirstName; }
    string GetLastName() { return WorkerLastName; }
    string GetNumber() { return WorkerNumber; }         
};

class GarageList {
    Garage List[500];                
    int MaxSize;
    int Size;
public:
    GarageList() 
    {
        MaxSize = 500;
    }

    ... //list out functions
};
```

That is an abridged version of my setup.  I can't figure out how to make a map with a reference id based on last name and a value which would contain all of the attributes of the garage class.  I guess something like map< string, Garage List[500] > directory.

Answer (score 2):

You are close. What you are looking for is:

```
map<string, Garage>;
```

With this in your GarageList class, you don't need to worry about number of entries, the map will manage that for you.

So GarageList would look like this:

```
class GarageList {
    map<string, Garage> garages_;                
public:
    GarageList() 
    {
    }

    int Size() {
        return garages_.size();
    }

    void AddGarage(const Garage& garage) {
        garages_[garage.GetLastName()] = garage;
    }

    // Return true if found, false otherwise
    bool FindGarage(const string& lastName, Garage& foundGarage) {
        if (garages_.find(lastName) != garages_.end()) {
            foundGarage = garages_[lastName];
            return true;
        }
        return false; // garage not found with lastName
    }
            return 
    ... //list out functions
 };
```

Comment: Well I got it to return 0, but when I create a new record into the array it doesn't reflect so in the map.  And how would I make the key of the map based on the WorkerLastName ?

Comment: t's not clear to me how important this list of Garage(s) is to you so let me write a little more of this class by editing my answer (adding garage and finding garage).

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want a map of name to an array ? Then you can use `map<string, vector<Garage> >`.